# Is there a way of capturing element state before MutationObserver mechanism fires (onVisibilityChanged)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, mutation-observers

I am trying to get the information on change in element state using Javascript `MutationObserver`
to get what was the state of the element before the change then check what is current state and based on that make some decisions.

Basically I am trying implement `onVisibilityChanged` event.

I am capturing any change on elements that I care about, then I do check if they are visible or not. Then if visibility is different to what it was broadcast `visibilityChanged`.
I know workaround I could do, since I am getting changes that happened I could create clone of element (`MutationEvent[0].target`) and revert apply all changes then check if clone is visible, this however sounds 'hacky' and inefficient so I was wondering is there a way of capturing element right before mutation happened. I do understand it's a long-shot since `MutationObserver` is fired after all changes happened and it's like travelling in time, yet I am all ears for your suggestions.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
var itemFromThePast = mutations[0].MagicTimeMachine().GetMeTheItemBeforeItWasChanged; // this is the line that is missing
if ($(itemFromThePast).is(":visible") != $(mutations[0].target).is(":visible"))
      {
       console.log('I win!');
      }
    
});
var targets = $('.ui-collapsible-content');

$.each(targets, function(i,target){
observer.observe(target, { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData : true,     characterDataOldValue : true });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this.
Works only on visibility changes that are made by class change.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    var clone = $(mutations[0].target).clone();
    clone.removeClass();
    for(var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++){
        clone.addClass(mutations[i].oldValue);
    }
    $(document.body).append(clone);
    var cloneVisibility = $(clone).is(":visible");
    $(clone).remove();
    if (cloneVisibility != $(mutations[0].target).is(":visible")){
        var visibilityChangedEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
        visibilityChangedEvent.initEvent('visibilityChanged', true, true);
        mutations[0].target.dispatchEvent(visibilityChangedEvent);
    }
});

var targets = $('.ui-collapsible-content');
$.each(targets, function(i,target){
    target.addEventListener('visibilityChanged', function(){ console.log('Kaboom babe');});
    observer.observe(target, { attributes: true, attributeFilter : ['class'], childList: false, attributeOldValue: true });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there are better alternatives. As a modern approach, I would suggest the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), with some good examples on the following pages. This API is designed to be notified when an element is not, partially or fully visible.